# How to order a list of tuples by second element given that it is already ordered by first element

Tags: python

So I have a list like this:

```
list_ = [(3, 2), (2, 2), (2, 1), (1, 3), (1, 2), (1, 1)]
```

And I would like to sort it so that the first elements remain in the same order i.e. 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, but the second elements are ordered the opposite way so it's like this:

```
list_ = [(3, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3)]
```

I can't seem to think of a simple way of doing this. (I'm quite new to programming.

Edit: A further example would be to order this list:

```
[(2,3), (3,2), (1,3), (3,4), (5,1)]
```

So that it becomes this:

```
[(5,1), (3,2), (3,4), (2,3), (1,3)]
```

i.e. the tuples are ordered such that the first elements are in decreasing order and where the first element is the same the tuples are ordered with second elements in increasing order.

Comment: Some answers are appearing that assume the order of the first elements is something that can be expressed easily as part of the sort function.  From your wording of the question, I'm assuming this is *not* allowed, but please clarify (by either saying it's allowed, or giving a different example in which the order of the first elements must be preserved but isn't expressible in any obvious way by a function)

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion. It is allowed. In the program I am writing I have created this list such that the first elements are in decreasing order. I want to be able to settle any ties in the first element by having the tuple with lower second element to go first in the list. Does that make sense?

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, it is clear now.  So you want to sort primarily by the first elements, decreasing, and secondarily by the second elements, increasing.   So, I think all of the answers on the page right now are valid answers.  Lots of options :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can group by first element and then sort the elements for each group:

```
from itertools import groupby
l = [(3, 2), (2, 2), (2, 1), (1, 3), (1, 2), (1, 1)]
l = [
    v for first, items in groupby(l, key=lambda x: x[0])
    for v in sorted(items, key=lambda x: x[1])
]
```

Result:

```
[(3, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3)]
```

If the first element has to be sorted in descending order, then you can sort first by second element and then **stable** sort by first element.

```
>>> l.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
>>> l.sort(key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=True)
>>> l
[(3, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3)]
```

Comment: Very nice answer, covering both bases and introducing groupby which seems to be an ideal tool for this kind of job.

Answer (score 0):

When sorting, you can define functions to be called prior to making the comparisons. One possible way which should work in your case is to define a function like this:

```
def get_key(item):
    return (-item[0], item[1])
```

This works because in Python it's possible to compare tuples by comparing values at the appropriate positions. This key function makes the sorting algorithm choose the pairs whose first element has the greatest values first, and then all ties are settled by choosing elements with smaller values first.

You could then sort the list by calling sorted and setting the parameter `key` to the previously described function.

```
>>> list_[(3, 2), (2, 2), (2, 1), (1, 3), (1, 2), (1, 1)]
>>>> sorted(list_, key=get_key)
[(3, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3)]
```

Comment: This works, however the wording of the original question leads me to think that involving -item[0] in the sort criteria isn't allowed-- that is, the first elements must remain in the same order, but we can't rely on it being any particular order that can be expressed in a function.  I added a comment to the question asking for clarification on this.

Comment: You're right, the wording of the question is ambiguous.I assumed that the initial list is sorted in descending order with respect to the first element in tuple, but it' possible, according to the description, that the initial list really isn't sorted at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
print sorted(list_, key=lambda x:(-x[0],x[1]))
```

Output:

```
[(3, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3)]
```